# How can I implement an animation on this change of page in flutter? using changenotifierprovider

Tags: flutter

[image]

I am trying to implement an animation which makes the second page come from right and the first page come from left. like animation in MaterialPageRoute. This is my code. Do I have to use pageroute to get an animation like it? Since there's a bottom nav bar and a custom appbar in my app. I wouldn't like to use pageroute for this. any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'selection.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(
      providers: [ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Selection())],
      child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
          child: Container(
            height: 32,
            width: deviceSize.width,
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.notifications_none_outlined),
                Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                  "address",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                )),
                Icon(Icons.search_rounded),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 48,
          width: deviceSize.width,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 42,
                width: deviceSize.width,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextButton(
                        child: Text("idle",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                color: context.watch<Selection>().selected
                                    ? Color(0xFF616161)
                                    : Color(0xFF2ac1bc))),
                        onPressed: () {
                          context.read<Selection>().setFalse();
                          animationController.reverse();
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextButton(
                        child: Text("selected",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                color: context.watch<Selection>().selected
                                    ? Color(0xFF2ac1bc)
                                    : Color(0xFF616161))),
                        onPressed: () {
                          context.read<Selection>().setTrue();
                          animationController.forward();
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.topLeft, children: [
                  PositionedTransition(
                      rect: RelativeRectTween(
                        begin: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
                            0, 0, deviceSize.width / 2, 0),
                        end: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
                            deviceSize.width / 2, 0, 0, 0),
                      ).animate(animationController),
                      child: Container(
                          width: deviceSize.width / 2,
                          height: 1,
                          color: Colors.pinkAccent)),
                ]),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: context.watch<Selection>().selected
              ? Container(
                  color: Color(0xFF2ac1bc),
                )
              : Container(color: Color(0xFF616161)),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use PageView for the content part, use PageController to change index of PageView will get the effect of 'the second page come from right and the first page come from left'

Comment: Thanks a lot. I totally forgot PageView, even though I am using it in my app haha.